# Bream and Neon Fish

Tags: fish

My daughter has a little bream in her tank and doesn't want to get rid of it. We haven't tried adding other fish into the tank due to we don't know of any other fish are compatible to be in the same tank. She is wanting to put neon fish in with her bream and we are wanting to know if these two types of fish are compatible with each other?

Comment: What size does the tank have  and what is the temperature? Also, what kind of bream is it? Adult size is around 50cm (20 inch), so unless you have a very very big tank, you'll need to get rid of it eventually...